# vue.js binding value from dynamically generated input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the below code for generating comments (cutted down for simplicity sake):

```
<div v-for="(g, gi) in submission.goals" :key="gi">
    <div>
        <p >Goal #{{gi+1}}</p>
        <div>{{g.text}}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Comments:</p>
        <div><span class="uk-text-small uk-text-muted"><i>no comments</i></span></div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <a href="" @click="submitComment(g.id, g.user_id, g.phase, $event)"></a>
            <textarea class="comment-input" placeholder="type your comment here"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my method look like this:

```
submitComment(gid,uid,phase,e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    //var comment -> get the value of the closes textaraea here
    console.log(gid, uid, phase, comment);

    //here I will make the ajax call to the API
}
```

As you can see the whole thing is generated in a `v-for` loop generating divs according to the size of the *submission.goals* array returned by the API.

My question is how can I get the value from the *textarea* input closest to the anchor that is calling the submit function.

Obviously I can't have a separate data object for each comment area since I do not have a control over the size of submission.goals array. And if I use `v-model="comment"` on each input, whatever user types in will be automatically propagated to each and every textarea.

I know how to handle this with jQuery, but with Vue.js I am still in the early learning stages.

Comment: `And if I use v-model="comment"`.  Have you tried `:v-model="comment[${gi}]"` so the model relations are independent?

Comment: @Taplar Isn't the `v-` prefix making the `:` redundant ?

Comment: Possibly.  I'm not completely up on the vue directives.  The main point i'm trying to make here is to try to use the indexing to differentiate the models

Comment: Maybe `<textarea v-model="g.comment"`? And pass whole `g` like `submitComment(g, $event)`, so inside that method you can get comment from `g.comment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark the text area as a ref, you could have a list of textarea elements. With the index number of the v-for items (gi in your case), you can get the [gi] element of the refs list and submit its value.

```
<a href="" @click="submitComment(g.id, g.user_id, g.phase, $event, gi)"></a>
<textarea ref="comment" class="comment-input" placeholder="type your comment here"></textarea>
```

```
submitComment(gid,uid,phase,e, gi)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = this.$refs.comment[gi].value;
    console.log(gid, uid, phase, comment);

    //here I will make the ajax call to the API
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change `submission.goals` to computed `submissionGoals` and create this computed with the code above:

```
submissionGoals(){
  return this.submission.goals.map(goal => ({...goal, comment: ''}));
}
```

Use `v-model="g.comment"` on textarea.
Now change `submitComment(g.id, g.user_id, g.phase, $event)` to `submitComment(g, $event)` like [Alexander Yakushev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8528080/alexander-yakushev) sayed.